# WPF ListView Items Filter - Filter not triggered after refresh Items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, itemcollection

I'm trying to add a Filter to my ListView. The filter depends on an input from a TextBox. I'm adding a filter to the ListView and trigger a Refresh if the TextBox Input is changed. My Problem: The Filter Method is only called once.

What I have:

I got a ListView in a XAML file.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="textBoxGroupLayers" FontSize="14" TextChanged="textBoxGroupLayers_TextChanged"/>
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listViewGroupLayers" FontSize="14" />
```

I'm adding Items to the ListView via

```
listViewGroupLayers.Items.Add(itemToAdd);
```

I'm adding the Filter:

```
this.listViewGroupLayers.Items.Filter = UserFilter;
```

Notice: listViewGroupLayers is a ListView and listViewGroupLayers.Items is an ItemCollection.

My Filter:

```
       private bool UserFilter(object item)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBoxGroupLayers.Text))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            MyObject myObject = (item as ListViewItem).Tag as MyObject;
            if (myObject == null)
            {
                 return true;
            }
            bool itemShouldBeVisible = myObject.Name.IndexOf(this.textBoxGroupLayers.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
            return itemShouldBeVisible;
        }
    }
```

The Refresh:

```
        private void textBoxGroupLayers_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
        this.listViewGroupLayers.Items.Refresh();     
    }
```

Now happens the following:
I setted a Breakpoint in the UserFilter. If I type the first letter in the TextBox, the Breakpoint is gonna be active and the filter is working fine. But if I type the second letter now, the filter isn't called.

If I just do the following, everything works fine:

```
        private void textBoxGroupLayers_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
        this.listViewGroupLayers.Items.Filter = UserFilter;     
    }
```

But this seems pretty dirty to me. 
My question:
Why isn't the filter working after the first time called? 
I checked the instance of `this.listViewGroupLayers.Items` and it always has the filter object.

Comment: What is `ListView.Items.Filter`? Haven't used it yet. I only use `CollectionView` filter (see [tutorial](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/)).

Comment: @Sinatr the filter is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2                  In your example they are using a ItemSource, but I don't have one.

Comment: Heres a question: why should this text box care about how to filter these items? All it should really care about is holding the text, updating the text, and telling other elements that the text was updated. I would notify the listview that the text was updated and what the text was, which can then manually set the Filter. Then it wouldn't be so dirty.

Comment: I don't know why `Refresh()` is not working, you may have to work on [mcve], but I'd keep your workaround, since under a hood it simply [reassign](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemCollection.cs,b031d32357cada42) `Filter` of `CollectionView`.